# Split string with replace by multiple tags function

Tags: javascript

My string has HTML code. I need to split it to array by **br** and **strong** tags. Example of string:

`string = "<strong>There was once upon a time a king</strong> but where he reigned and what he was called, I do not know.<br>Then it was foretold to the king that his daughter would find her health by <strong>eating an apple.</strong><br>So he ordered it to be proclaimed throughout the whole of his kingdom...";`

Is it possible to identify splitting tag and:

1. If tag is **br** then add "\n" to the end of that part.
2. If tag is **strong** then add "[b]" to the beginning of that part.

So this is what I want to achieve:

```
"[b]There was once upon a time a king",
 "but where he reigned and what he was called, I do not know. \n",
 "Then it was foretold to the king that his daughter would find her health by ",
 "[b]eating an apple. \n",
 "So he ordered it to be proclaimed throughout the whole of his kingdom..."
```

I have tried

```
 var array = string.replace(/(<strong\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/strong>)|(<br>)/g,function(string,p1,p2) {
    if(p1) return '[b]$1';
    if(p2) return ' \n';
});
```

but that did not help me.

```js
string = "<strong>There was once upon a time a king</strong> but where he reigned and what he was called, I do not know.<br>Then it was foretold to the king that his daughter would find her health by <strong>eating an apple.</strong><br>So he ordered it to be proclaimed throughout the whole of his kingdom...";
var array = string.replace(/(<strong\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/strong>)|(<br>)/g,function(string,p1,p2) {
        if(p1) return '[b]$1';
        if(p2) return ' \n';
    });

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I don't really get what your desired output is. Or is it about the undefineds in the text?

Comment: Hi @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze I just want to split string by tags into array

Comment: But in your example just the whole text is in an array at the end, which does not seem to add any information to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just would use javascripts split join and replace all tags either with nothing for e.g `</strong>` which you dont need or with the correct thing for the given tag.

```js
let text = "<strong>There was once upon a time a king</strong> but where he reigned and what he was called, I do not know.<br>Then it was foretold to the king that his daughter would find her health by <strong>eating an apple.</strong><br>So he ordered it to be proclaimed throughout the whole of his kingdom...";

const replaceTags = (text, tag, replacement) => {
  return text.split(tag).join(replacement);
}

const tags = [
  {tag: "<strong>", rep: "\n[b]" },
  {tag: "</strong>", rep: "" },
  {tag: "<br>", rep: " \n" },
  {tag: "<br/>", rep:  " \n" },
  {tag: "<br />", rep: " \n" },
  
];

tags.forEach(tag => {
  text = replaceTags(text, tag.tag, tag.rep);
});

if(text.startsWith("\n")) text = text.substring(1, text.length);

const texts = text.split("\n")

console.log(texts);
```

Comment: Thank you @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze there is one more split required where we have: [b] in the text e.g. [b]$1eating an apple.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: In the result we have a part - "Then it was foretold to the king that his daughter would find her health by [b]$1eating an apple." So it should be split to where we have [b]

Comment: @qqruza you mean like this?

Comment: Sorry now i get the array part.